# How to fix layout of list box with custom item template

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have applied a custom ItemTemplate to the ListBox control, but have an issue with the layout. When the ListBox is scrolled to the bottom and is resized the item overflows:

[image: ListBox Layout Issue]

It seems that if i scroll up the layout is eventually corrected:

[image: ListBox Corrected]

If i remove the line which sets the HorizontalContentAlignment the issue goes away (but i would like the list item to stretch to fill the available space)...

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<ListBox x:Name="myList" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"  Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>            
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Background="Lime" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Comments}"/>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="Aqua">
                        <Button Width="20" Height="20" Content="..."/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

The default `ItemsPanel` of a `ListBox` is a `VirtualizingStackPanel`, which copes badly with the `Stretch` alignment. Instead, try a `UniformGrid` with just one column.

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: While your suggestion does appear to work, without virtualisation the performance isn't good enough (i have been testing with up to 10000 items). One thing which does work is to add an event handler to the ListBox's SizeChanged event and call myList.Items.Refresh(). It doesn't feel like it should be necessary but so far its the best compromise I've come across, although its not without its performance issues (there is some significant stuttering resizing the window).